# Webcam application to save image to database

Tags: vb6

I want to create a webcam application that can save image to database. My code is from the internet. My code can only save binary but I guess my conversion was incorrect because I can't retrieve them from the database.

Here is my Code:

```
Private Sub cmdsave_Click()
OpenDB
rs.Open "tblimg", db, adOpenKeyset, adLockPessimistic, adCmdTable
Dim bytData() As Byte, PicInfo As BITMAP
If Dir(App.path & "\myPic", vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir (App.path & "\myPic")
File1.path = App.path & "\myPic"
'File1.Pattern = "*.bmp"
File1.Pattern = "*.jpg"
File1.Refresh
Dim Maxnum As Integer, ii As Integer
For ii = 0 To File1.ListCount - 1
    If Left(File1.List(ii), 1) = "p" Then
        If CInt(Mid(File1.List(ii), 2, Len(File1.List(ii)) - 4)) > Maxnum Then
            Maxnum = CInt(Mid(File1.List(ii), 2, Len(File1.List(ii)) - 4))
        End If
    End If
Next
    Picture1.Picture = Image1.Picture
    'SavePicture Image1.Picture, App.Path & "\myPic\p" & Maxnum + 1 & ".bmp"
    SAVEJPEG App.path & "\myPic\p" & Maxnum + 1 & ".jpg", 100, Me.Picture1
    ReDim bytData((PicInfo.bmHeight * PicInfo.bmWidth)) As Byte
    With rs
    .AddNew
    .Fields("Picture").AppendChunk bytData
    .Fields("Desc") = Label2.Caption
    .Update
    End With
Set rs = Nothing
db.Close: Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code give you idea of what you want to achive

```
       Picture3.Visible = True
       SavePicture Picture1.Picture, App.Path & "\Emp Photo\" & UCase(Trim(G_EmpCode)) _ & ".jpg"

       Picture3.Picture = LoadPicture(App.Path & "\Emp Photo\" & UCase(Trim(G_EmpCode)) & ".jpg")
       Picture2.Picture = LoadPicture(App.Path & "\Emp Photo\" & UCase(Trim(G_EmpCode)) & ".jpg")

   FrmEmployee.Image1.Picture = Picture2.Picture

  CCTVImagePath = App.Path & "\Emp Photo\" & UCase(Trim(G_EmpCode)) & ".jpg"

 Call cmdClose_Click
Call CmdStart_Click

If CCTVImagePath <> "" Then
   ImagePath = CCTVImagePath
   m_imgfile = CCTVImagePath
End If

If FileSystemObj.FileExists(ImagePath) = True Then
    Set strStream = New ADODB.Stream
    strStream.Type = adTypeBinary
    strStream.Open
    Sourcefile = ImagePath
    strStream.LoadFromFile Sourcefile
    CCTVImagePath = ""
End If

CCTVImagePath = ""
```